# Downgrade composer version 2 to 1

Tags: magento2, composer

```
The "magento/magento-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.0") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
The "magento/inventory-composer-installer" plugin was skipped because it requires a Plugin API version ("^1.1") that does not match your Composer installation ("2.0.0"). You may need to run composer update with the "--no-plugins" option.
```

I am facing the above issue, I need to downgrade Magento2 composer version. How can i downgrade composer version 2 to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply run `composer self-update version_number`
Example:`composer self-update 1.10.0`

You can check composer available versions here https://getcomposer.org/download/

Comment: composer downgrade successfully, but the issue still remains.

Comment: @Yogesh did you try `composer update --ignore-platform-reqs` ?

Comment: its something pipeline issue in our bitbucket.